# How can i make an Image() disappear in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, object

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TileMap2</title>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      outline: 3px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="1000"></canvas>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      drawMap();
      context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
      context.drawImage(goomba, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    }




    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var xpos = 0;
    var ypos = 0;
    var grass = new Image();
    var water = new Image();
    var dirt = new Image();
    var mario = new Image();
    var goomba = new Image();

    mario.src = 'Mario.png';
    grass.src = 'grass1.jpg';
    water.src = 'water.jpg';
    dirt.src = 'dirt.jpg';
    goomba.src = "goomba.png";



    var map = [
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    ];

    function drawMap() {
      var localX = 0;
      var localY = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {

          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 0) {
            context.drawImage(grass, localX, localY);
          }

          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 1) {
            context.drawImage(dirt, localX, localY)
          };
          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 2) {
            context.drawImage(water, localX, localY);
          }
          localX += 100;
        }
        localX = 0;
        localY += 100;
      }


    }



    function kill() {
      if (mario.left === goomba.left && mario.top === goomba.top) {
        goomba.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    kill();

    function move(e) {


      if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        xpos += 50;
      }


      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        xpos -= 50;
      }

      if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        ypos -= 50;
      }

      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        ypos += 50;
      }
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawMap();
      context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
      context.drawImage(goomba, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    document.onkeydown = move;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Does anyone know how i can make the kill() function work?
Whenever mario has the same coordinates as goomba i want goomba to be erased from the screen. Please only in Javascript. This is my first javascript project so please show some patience :)**

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: It looks like you try to hide goomba by setting its display style to none as you would do with an html element, but since goomba is an image you draw manually to the canvas, couldn't you just redraw without goomba? ( `if(!goombakilled) context.drawImage(goomba ..etc` ) where `goombakilled` is a global variable. (one step further would be to have all images inside objects that contain the image position and alive state, but that's perhaps a bit too much at once for a first project)

Comment: Part of the question is also how to detect the collision itself?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function you will use for drawing. Currently you are doing it repeatedly, which makes your code difficult to maintain.

But before that, we should just create a set of `images`, like this:

```
var images = {};

function addToImage(key, obj, x, y) {
    images[key] = {obj: obj, x: x, y: y, display: true};
}
```

When you initialize, add `mario` and `goomba` to images and their initial location and then implement a function to draw. So, let's have this function:

```
function draw(images) {
    drawMap();
    for (var imageIndex in images) {
        if (images[imageIndex].display) {
            context.drawImage(images[imageIndex].obj.src, images[imageIndex].x, images[imageIndex].y, images[imageIndex].obj.width, images[imageIndex].obj.height);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    draw(images);
}
```

When you kill `goomba`, just set `images["goomba"].display` to `false` and call `draw(images)` again.

Comment: I added this to my current code:                                                                                                   var images=[mario,goomba];
function addToImage(key, obj, x, y) {  images[key] = {obj: obj, x: x, y: y, display: true};
}
function draw(images) {
    drawMap();
    for (var imageIndex in images) {
if (images[imageIndex].display) {
context.drawImage(images[imageIndex].obj.src, images[imageIndex].x, images[imageIndex].y, images[imageIndex].obj.width, images[imageIndex].obj.height);} }
}
window.onload = function() {
    draw(images);
}    Mario and Goomba disappear...

Comment: Take a look at the addToImage function, there you add the images into the set. You can call it likte addToImage("goomba", goomba, 0, 0), after that you can reach it with images["goomba"]